# Can't write image data to path on the production server Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I know this is very general problem and I have tried so many answers but it didn't worked.

Here is my code

```
 if(Input::hasFile('image_small')){

                    $image = Input::file('image_small');
                    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

                    if (!File::exists(public_path('images/album/small/'.$albumcode.'/'.$filename))){ 
                    $path = public_path('images/album/small/'.$albumcode);

                    // dd(public_path('images/album/'.$albumcode));

                    File::makeDirectory(public_path('images/album/'.$albumcode));
                    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(256,256)->save($path.'/'.$filename);

                    $album->album_art = 'images/album/small/'.$albumcode.'/'.$filename ;

                    }
                }
```

> Can't write image data to path
>   (/var/www/madmuziktest/public/images/album/small/MAD_ALBUM-2016-0001/xxxx.jpg)

in my public folder

I have 777 for
/public/images/album/small

and 775 for /public/images

**Laravel.log**

```
[2016-06-01 09:47:22] local.ERROR: exception 'Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException' with message 'Can't write image data to path (/var/www/madmuziktest/public/images/album/small/MAD_ALBUM-2016-0001/xxxx.jpg)' in /var/www/madmuziktest/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php:143
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/madmuziktest/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php(177): Intervention\Image\Image->save('/var/www/madmuz...')
#1 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\AdminController->postUploadalbum(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/madmuziktest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/madmuziktest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('postUploadalbum', Array)
#4 /var/www/madmuziktest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\AdminController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'postUploadalbum')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /var/www/madmuziktest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/madmuziktest/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/madmuziktest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/madmuziktest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message from the Laravel log and from the Apache error log?

Comment: @TheFallen can you please tell me where to find the laravel log ?

Comment: It should be in **storage/logs/laravel.log**.

Comment: @TheFallen I have added the log file from Laravel , But I am using NGINX so trying to find the error file of that

Comment: I know you said you have folder rights, but from the Intervention package I see that it fails on **file_put_contents()**, so can you run `chmod -R 777 public` and try again?

Comment: @TheFallen it works ty!